# Can I use the same editor for Control.Anchor property for my own user control's designer support?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, user-controls

I have a simple extender component that draws 3D borders around any Control.  In my designer supprot for the component, I'd like to use the same editor that VS uses to select the Anchor property.

I know I can use the [Editor()] attribute, but I don't know the class name of the editor that's used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used .NET Reflector to find the answer:

```
[Flags, 
Editor("System.Windows.Forms.Design.AnchorEditor, System.Design, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a", typeof(UITypeEditor))]
public enum AnchorStyles
```